# How to find characters in two String that cause them become unequal?

Tags: java

I want to find characters in two String that make them unequal and print them.

for example:

```
String str1 = "abcd";
String str2 = "abc";
```

output = "d"

The code that I use is look like this:

```
public void removeUnequalChars() {
String str1 = "abcd";
String str2 = "abc";



    String commonChars = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
                    commonChars += str.charAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < commonChars.length(); i ++)
        {
            String charToRemove = commonChars.charAt(i)+"";
            str = str.replace(charToRemove, "");
            str2 = str2.replace(charToRemove, "");

        }


        String s3= str+str2;

        System.out.println(s3);
}
```

But the problem with code is that if we have duplicate characters, this solution does not work. 
for example :

```
String str1 = "abccd";
String str2 = "abc";
```

expected output is "cd" but the above code print just "d"

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: What about "abc" vs "cba", is the result "ac" or...?

Comment: no they are equal.

Comment: You want to find the minimum number of characters to append to one of the strings so that the two are anagrams of each other?

Comment: i think you have to give more examples?
are you really just intrested in the number of occurences of a character? like
str1 = aaa and str2 = bbaaa should print bb?

Comment: No I want to find characters that cause two string become unequal.

Comment: what should be the result for "ccd" and "abxqr"?

Comment: yes it should print bb. @Axel M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using str.replace(), you could use str.replaceFirst() to keep other occurrences of the characters.

You will also just need to use the shorter string in place of commonChars, and then also keep track of any characters in the shorter string that arent in the longer one.

So it would look like:

```
public String uncommonCharacters(String str, String str2){
    String shorterString;
    String longerString;

    if (str.length() < str2.length()){
        shorterString = str;
        longerString = str2;
    } else {
        shorterString = str2;
        longerString = str;
    }

    StringBuilder charsNotInLongString = new StringBuilder();
    for(String charToRemove : shorterString.split("")) {
        String newLongerString = longerString.replaceFirst(charToRemove, "");
        if (newLongerString.equals(longerString)) {
            charsNotInLongString.append(charToRemove);
        } else {
            longerString = newLongerString;
        }
    }

    return longerString + charsNotInLongString.toString();
}
```

edit: woops didnt realise it was getting added twice to the commonChars, updated based on comments.

Update: Just got home, updated to be prettier

Comment: I try this, but the output is still wrong. print only "d" not "cd"

Comment: how does this improve anything? the output for the given example is still d

Comment: I think they could simplify this a bit by skipping commonChars and simply looping through the shorter String and doing a replaceFirst on both strings for each character in the shorter string. At the end the shorter string should be empty and the longer String should contain anything that was not in the shorter one.

Comment: sorry realized how i hadn't thought my answer through.... went on an editing rampage hopefully its good now

Comment: Good to know that there is `replaceFirst` function.

Answer (score 2):

here is my attempt with string builders

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    removeUnequalChars("abcd", "abc");
    removeUnequalChars("abccd", "abc");
}

public static void removeUnequalChars(String str1Input, String str2Input) {
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(str1Input);
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(str2Input);

    for (int i = 0; i < sb1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sb2.length(); j++) {
            if (sb1.charAt(i) == sb2.charAt(j)) {
                sb1.deleteCharAt(i--);
                sb2.deleteCharAt(j--);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb1.append(sb2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if a character is already on the commonChars array, adding `commonChars.contains(str.charAt(i))` into the equal validation.

```
for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j) && commonChars.contains(str.charAt(i)) {
                commonChars += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
class basic {
    public static void removeUnequalChars(String str, String str2) {
        String uncommonChars = "";
        int maxlength = str.length();
        if (maxlength < str2.length())
            maxlength = str2.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
            if (i >= str.length()) {
                uncommonChars += str2.charAt(i);
                continue;
            } else if (i >= str2.length()) {
                uncommonChars += str.charAt(i);
                continue;
            }               
            if (str.charAt(i) != str2.charAt(i)) {
                uncommonChars += str2.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(uncommonChars);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        removeUnequalChars("abc", "abcd");
        removeUnequalChars("abc", "abccd");
        removeUnequalChars("bocd", "avcod");
    }       
}
```

Output:

```
d
cd
avod
```

Comment: @Charles but not on same positions.

Comment: @Charles since OP says: `expected output is "cd" but the above code print just "d"` for "abccd" and "abc".

Comment: check out the first comment `What about "abc" vs "cba", is the result "ac" or...?` and the response `no they are equal.`

Comment: hm... Then he wants the output of `n` timed matches? if string1 contains 2 c and string2 contains 2 c then they are removed, if only 1 c then printed.

Comment: They are equal. @Charles

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them and then analyze them:

```
const s1 = 'acb';
const s2 = 'abccd';

let s1Sort = s2.split('').sort();
let s2Sort = s2.split('').sort();
Math.max(s1.length, s2.length) === s1.length ? s1Sort = s1.split('').sort() : s2Sort = s1.split('').sort();
const unequal = [];

for(let i=0; i< Math.max(s1.length, s2.length); i++){    
    s1Sort[i] !== s2Sort[i] ? unequal.push(s1Sort[i]) : '';
}

return unequal.join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

There three cases are exist:

1. First string is larger than second one
2. Vice versa
3. The strings have the same length

... and then just a comparison of the strings by the same index in order to find the difference.

That's how it looks like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class Main {

    private static List<Character> compare(String str1, String str2) {

        if (str1 == null || str1.isEmpty())
            return stringToChars(str2);

        if (str2 == null || str2.isEmpty())
            return stringToChars(str1);

        if (str1.equals(str2))
            return Collections.emptyList();

        List<Character> diff = new ArrayList<>();

        char[] arr1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] arr2 = str2.toCharArray();

        if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {

           diff.addAll(compare90Degrees(Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr2.length), arr2));
           diff.addAll(stringToChars(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr1, arr2.length, arr1.length))));

        } else if (arr1.length < arr2.length) {

            diff.addAll(compare90Degrees(arr1, Arrays.copyOf(arr2, arr1.length)));
            diff.addAll(stringToChars(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr2, arr1.length, arr2.length))));

        } else {
            diff.addAll(compare90Degrees(arr1, arr2));
        }

        return diff;
    }

    private static List<Character> compare90Degrees(char[] arr1, char[] arr2) {

        if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("arrays are differ in length");

        List<Character> mismatch = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

            char c = arr1[i];

            if (c != arr2[i])
                mismatch.add(c);
        }

        return mismatch;
    }

    // to boxed collection
    private static List<Character> stringToChars(String str) {
        return str.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(compare("qwerty", "qwry"));

        // prints [e, r, t, y]
    }
 }
```

Func `compare("qwerty", "qwry")`. The first string is compared to second one.

`e` symbol is not present at all, the rest ones have wrong index.